# Simplify this expression with radical signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is-
Simplify:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}} - \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}}$$

My answer is $2\sqrt{3}$.
Am I right? I would also like to know the solution as I am a bit confused about whether to take absolute values while solving it.

Comment: Answer is right. No absolute values should be used.

Comment: You're probably thinking of your previous question, where there were expressions of the form $\sqrt{A^2}$. In that case, it's true that $\sqrt{A^2}=|A|$, but now of course *that appears nowhere here*.

Comment: @meg_1997: I assume you did the problem by rationalizing the denominators *separately*. If you used another way, say so, rationalizing denominators gives a simple solution.

Comment: Say, why is it called rationalizing the denominator anyways? I didn't know that denominators were unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct, and no absolute values are necessary.